# Simulating abstract classes in Ruby (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to simulate an abstract class in Ruby on Rails. I.e. I want to raise an exception if someone tries to call `Abstract.new`, but he should be able to call `Child.new` (while `Child < Abstract`).

How to do this? Overwriting both `new` and `initialize` does not work.

Comment: You'll be much happier in Ruby not doing this.  Ruby neither needs this nor (as you are finding out) does it really support it.

Comment: Would like to see what mr. @Jörg W Mittag has to say about this.

Comment: If you must... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512466/how-to-implement-an-abstract-class-in-ruby

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why would you want to do this? The point of abstract/interfaced classes are to hack Strongly typed languages into a dynamic paradigm. If you need your class to fit in the signature, name your methods according to the original class or make a facade and plug it in, no need to trick a compiler into allowing it, it just works.

```
def my_printer obj
  p obj.name
end
```

So I defined the interface as any object with a name property

```
class person
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize
   @name = "Person"
  end
end

class Employee
   attr_accessor :name
  def initialize
   @name = "Employee"
   @wage = 23
  end
end
```

so nothing stops us from calling our printer method with either of these

```
my_printer Person.new
my_printer Employee.new
```

both print there names without a hitch :D

Comment: Basically, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: A good comment by the way, but I agree with apnea.diving.deep

Comment: I want/need to do this to avoid code duplication. In fact my abstract class is not really abstract, it has some attributes needed by all its subclasses and has some accessor for them.

Comment: @d135-1r43, based upon that comment, modules may do well for you.  I've amended my answer to show how.

Comment: This is an answer, I explained quite clearly how to accomplish the functionality of an abstract class without breaking the ruby paradigm.

Comment: In Ruby, the *only* point of a class is that it can be instantiated. Using a language construct whose sole raison-d'être is the ability to be instantiated and then asking how to make it so it can't be instantiated doesn't make sense. So, not only is this an answer, it's a pretty good one. +1.

Comment: This is an answer hidden in a comment-like paragraph allright. Some example code would make it into a **good** answer.

Answer (score 12):

In another comment, the OP mentions that the purpose of the abstract class is to share behavior (methods) needed by its children.  In Ruby, that's often best done with a module used to "mix in" methods where needed.  For example, instead of:

```
class Abstract
  def foo
    puts "foo!"
  end
end

class Concrete
end

Concrete.new.foo # => "foo!"
```

this:

```
module Foo
  def foo
    puts "foo!"
  end
end

class Concrete
  include Foo
end

Concrete.new.foo # => "foo!"
```

---

But here's how the original request might be satisfied:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

class Abstract

  def initialize(*args)
    raise if self.class == Abstract
    super
  end

end

class Concrete < Abstract
end

Concrete.new # OK
Abstract.new # Raises an exception
```

Comment: +1 Mixins for [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

You almost always need to do this to enforce an API, when some third party is going to implement some stub, and you're sure they're going to mess it up. You can use specific prefix-templates in your parent class and a module that introspects on creation to achieve this:

```
module Abstract
  def check
    local = self.methods - Object.methods
    templates = []
    methods = []
    local.each do |l|
      if l =~ /abstract_(.*)/ # <--- Notice we look for abstract_* methods to bind to.
        templates.push $1
      end
      methods.push l.to_s
    end
    if !((templates & methods) == templates)
      raise "Class #{self.class.name} does not implement the required interface #{templates}"
    end
  end
end

class AbstractParent 
  include Abstract
  def initialize
    check
  end
  def abstract_call # <--- One abstract method here
  end
  def normal_call
  end
end

class Child < AbstractParent # <-- Bad child, no implementation
end

class GoodChild < AbstractParent
  def call # <-- Good child, has an implementation
  end
end
```

Test:

```
begin
  AbstractParent.new
  puts "Created AbstractParent"
rescue Exception => e
  puts "Unable to create AbstractParent"
  puts e.message
end

puts

begin
  Child.new
  puts "Created Child"
rescue Exception => e
  puts "Unable to create Child"
  puts e.message
end

puts

begin
  GoodChild.new
  puts "Created GoodChild"
rescue Exception => e
  puts "Unable to create GoodChild"
  puts e.message
end
```

Result:

```
[~] ruby junk.rb 
Unable to create AbstractParent
Class AbstractParent does not implement the required interface ["call"]

Unable to create Child
Class Child does not implement the required interface ["call"]

Created GoodChild
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this for doing STI, you could follow the suggestions in [this thread](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=111682#p111682):

```
class Periodical < ActiveRecord::Base
  private_class_method :new, :allocate
  validates_presence_of :type
end

class Book < Periodical
  public_class_method :new, :allocate
end

class Magazine < Periodical
  public_class_method :new, :allocate
end
```

Caveat: I'm not sure if this is a working solution. This hides `new` and `allocate` in the base class and re-enables them in child classes -- but that alone does not seem to prevent objects being created with `create!`. Adding the validation on `type` prevents the base class from being created. I guess you could also hide `create!`, but I'm not sure if that covers all the ways Rails can instantiate a model object.