# Rails 3 ActiveRecord abstract objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to instantiate an object of abstract AR class for testing purposes. The model's defined like this:

```
class Basic < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def stuff
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end
```

When I try to `Basic.new`, I get:

```
"Mysql2::Error: Table 'project_development.basics' doesn't exist"
```

Is it normal behavior? Do abstract AR classes are not intended to be instantiated even without (obviously impossible) persistence?

Using 1.9.2-p136 with Rails 3.0.4 / Mysql2 0.2.6

**Edit:**

It turns out that the error is caused by column definitions, which in the case of an abstract model cannot be fetched from the database.

```
class Basic < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  @columns = []
end
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Ruby programmers tend to dislike abstract classes. Including modules does not work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512466/how-to-implement-an-abstract-class-in-ruby

Comment: @tokland; Really? I'd have to disagree with that. Abstract classes are very useful and are used very often. `ActiveRecord::Base` is an abstract class, for example. I do agree that the way some people use abstract classes could be better served by using modules, though.

Comment: @idlefingers. Sorry, that was too bold a statement, indeed abstract classes may be useful in certain scenarios.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. Abstract classes are not supposed to be instantiated. You should test the classes which inherit from the abstract class, not the abstract class itself.

Comment: +1, this is typical in many dynamic languages. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619941/simulating-abstract-classes-in-ruby-rails