# Is there a way to restrict Ruby Class initialization only to a subclass?

Tags: ruby

I'm in the process of creating a library that powers a network of APIs.  The center of that library is currently a Client class which each API client subclasses.  Since I'm the one writing all my APIs, they'll all function similarly (restful, authorization through access_token, etc).

However unlike other ruby API Client libraries ([Twitter's](https://github.com/sferik/twitter), etc), the client class should not be instantiated directly.  That's because the library isn't restricted to a single API. Instead, each API client will subclass the Client class.  My question is as follows:

*Is there a way to require that a Ruby Class is only initialized through a subclass?*

Additionally, in reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282864/ruby-inheritance-vs-mixins) I decided that a class is better over a mixin here.

For those that want code, here's an example:

```
class A
    def initialize(options = {})
        #what goes on in here doesn't really matter for the purpose of this question
        #I just don't want it to be initialized directly
        options.each do |k,v|
            instance_variable_set("@#{k}",v) unless v.nil?
        end
    end
end

class B < A
    attr_accessor :class_specific_opt
    def initialize( options = {} )
        @class_specific_opt = "val" unless options[:class_specific_opt].nil?
        super(options)
    end
end
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you do `B.new`, then `B#initialize` will be called, which will call `A#initialize`. `A#initialize` will not be called directly unless you do `A.new`. What is wrong with it?

Comment: The issue is that someone could still theoretically call A#initialize

Comment: `initialize` is a private method. You cannot call it with a receiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an answer here on abstract-like classes: [How to implement an abstract class in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512466/how-to-implement-an-abstract-class-in-ruby),
Though you may still be better off providing A as a module and including it in its implementors.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
class A
  def self.initialize_allowed?
    raise "You cannot initialize instances of this class."
  end

  def self.allow_initialize
    class << self
      def initialize_allowed?
        true
      end
    end
  end

  def initialize(options = {})
    self.class.initialize_allowed?
    options.each do |k,v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
    end
  end
end
```

Calling `A.new` raises a RuntimeError and halts the `initialize` method. You can then override the `initialized_allowed?` method in subclasses by calling `allow initialize` on them. (maybe this is overkill, but I think `allow_initialize` is easier to read than `def self.initialize_allowed?;end`):

```
class B < A
  allow_initialize
end

B.new #=> #<B:0x00000102837d10>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want `A.new` to be called, simply do:

```
class <<A
  undef :new
end
```

Then, you will not be able to call it:

```
A.new #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for A:Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
private_class_method :new
```

to class A, and

```
public_class_method :new
```

to class B.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to make the new method `private`. This is exactly what the ruby `Singleton` module does. [Singleton Module Documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html)

```
class A
  private_class_method :new
end

class B < A
  public_class_method :new
end
```