# Integer and other (?) abstract classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I admit that in duck-typing languages, abstract classes aren't used so often, so this question is more out of curiosity than of actual need:

In Ruby (at least 2.0), `Fixnum` and `Bignum` have a common superclass called `Integer`. It looks to me, that this is an abstract class; at least, it can't be instantiated, i.e. when you do in irb:

```
irb(main):047:0> Integer.new(8)
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Integer:Class
    from (irb):47
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Now, if I would decide to roll out my own class which behaves like `Integer`, i.e. being "as abstract as `Integer` is", how would I do this? I thought that *every* class contains a (hidden) `new` method (which calls my `initialize` method if present).

Comment: Go through  this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512466/how-to-implement-an-abstract-class-in-ruby

Comment: Abstract base classes with strict enforcement like this do go against the usual Ruby style. If you really, really need to be a jerk about people instantiating your class: `def initialize; raise "Nope"; end` then let subclasses redefine that.

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. Or is it possible, that Ruby's integer class raises "NoMethodError: undefined method `new'"? If this were the case, I think the stack trace would show 'initialize' as the source of the exception, wouldn't it?

Comment: @BinaryMee: This would also not explain the wording of the exception I got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can undefine the `new` class method calling [`undef_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-undef_method) on the [singleton class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Singleton+Classes) of your class, for example:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    undef_method(:new)
  end
end

Foo.new
# NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Foo:Class
```

Or alternatively:

```
class Foo; end
Foo.singleton_class.send(:undef_method, :new)
```

**Update**: for the sake of completeness here's a quick (and possibly dirty) solution to the problem mentioned by @tadman in the comments. It uses the [`inherited`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-inherited) method to define a `new` singleton method for the subclasses of `Foo` that mimics the implementation of [`Class#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new):

```
class Foo
  class << self
    undef_method(:new)

    def inherited(subclass)
      subclass.define_singleton_method(:new) do |*args|
        obj = subclass.allocate
        obj.send(:initialize, *args)
        obj
      end
    end
  end

end

class Bar < Foo
  attr_reader :bar
  def initialize(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end
end

Bar.new('foobar').bar # => "foobar"
```

Comment: There's also the `undef` keyword.

Comment: Don't forget this will mean you need to add that back in for subclasses which could get kind of messy.

Comment: @toro2k: I think your solution is the right one. It explains at least the effect I see from instantiating an Integer. I wonder why a Ruby core class was defined as being abstract. It is a rarely used concept in duck-typing languages....