# Rescue exceptions for all methods in a class

Tags: ruby

Basically, this is normal code:

```
class Foo
   def hi
      # your code here....
   rescue => e
      # Raise error here
   end

   def hello
      # your code here...
   rescue => e
      # Raise error here
   end
end
```

But in PHP, i can use `__call` magic method to create abstract class, look like this:

```
class FooAbstract {
    public function __call($name, $args) {
       # Try catch in here...
    }
}

class Foo extends FooAbstract {
   public function hi() {
     # Code with try catch...
   }
}
```

How can i use __call method in Ruby class???

Comment: If you want to define a class, which can not be instantiated except if subclassed, you could do a `fail "Trying to instantiate abstract class" if self.class == FooAbstract` in FooAbstract#initialize.

Comment: This looks like a XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: There is no *direct* equivalent to `__call` in ruby; the closest is probably `method_missing`. (And likewise, there's no *direct* equivalent to `method_missing` in PHP, but as far as I know `__call` is probably the closest.) But as Stefan says, what are you actually trying to achieve here? I can't really advise how to structure the code without knowing what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: My guess is to accomplish something like the rails class level `rescue_from` so that you don't have to copy-paste the  same `rescue` block to every method.

Comment: It's also possible to do something this globally by defining `at_exit { Logger.new('/tmp/log').error($!) if $! }` if you for example just want to write out a log of all the exceptions. But this is global, not class level.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to illustrate with that PHP code, but there method `hi` will not invoke `__call` in any way.  What was `__call` supposed to do, add exception handling for all methods of child classes?

Comment: You could create a single interface for all method calls and wrap that e.g. `def call(method_name,*args,&block); begin;public_send(method_name,*args,&block);rescue;end;end`. Then `Foo.new.(:hi)` or `Foo.new.call(:hello)` However calling around this like `Foo.new.hi` would escape the handling

Answer (score 6):

You could define a module that when included defines a `method_added` hook that wraps all new methods inside a `begin..rescue` block:

```
require 'set'

module ExceptionHandler

  def self.included(klass)
    super
    klass.send(:extend, ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def exception_handler(&block)
      @__exception_handler = block.to_proc
    end

    def handle_exception(exception)
      defined?(@__exception_handler) ? @__exception_handler.call(exception) : super
    end

    def handle_method_exceptions(method_name)
      old_method = instance_method(method_name)
      return if (@__hooked_methods ||= Set.new).include?(method_name)

      @__ignoring_added_methods = true # avoid infinite define_method/method_added loop
      define_method method_name do |*args, &block|
        begin
          old_method.bind(self).(*args, &block)
        rescue => ex
          self.class.handle_exception(ex)
        end
      end
      @__ignoring_added_methods = false

      @__hooked_methods << method_name
    end

    def method_added(method_name)
      super
      unless @__ignoring_added_methods
        handle_method_exceptions(method_name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This would be used like:

```
class Foo
  include ExceptionHandler

  exception_handler do |exception|
    puts "Catched an exception:"
    puts "---------------------"
    puts "Exception class: #{exception.class}"
    puts "Message: #{exception.message}"
    puts "Backtrace:"
    puts exception.backtrace.join("\n  ")
    puts
    puts "reraising.."
    puts
    raise exception
  end

  def this_raises
    raise "somebody set up us the bomb"
  end
end

Foo.new.this_raises
```

This would output:

```
Catched an exception:
---------------------
Exception class: RuntimeError
Message: somebody set up us the bomb
Backtrace:
errorhandler.rb:62:in `this_raises'
  errorhandler.rb:26:in `call'
  errorhandler.rb:26:in `block in handle_exceptions'
  errorhandler.rb:67:in `<main>'

reraising..
```

I'm not sure if it is a good idea.

You could take out the `method_added` part and it would look something like:

```
class Foo
  with_rescue def foofoo(arg)
    puts arg.inspect
  end
end
```

(You can just rename the `handle_method_exceptions` to `with_rescue` and remove all the `@__ignoring_added_methods` trickery and the `method_added` method and it should work as described).

Comment: This is great! But how is it possible to use an instance method as the `exception_handler`?  I want to be able to log an exception in any method to my instance specific logger.

Comment: @meesern untested, but you can try to replace `self.class.handle_exception(ex)` with `(respond_to?(:handle_exception) ? self : self.class).send(:handle_exception, ex)` and define the exception handler as an instance method: `def handle_exception(ex)  ... end`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve here, but the Ruby equivalent of PHP's `__call()` is [`method_missing`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing).

By default, when you try to call a non-existing method you will get an exception. But if you want to implement an "abstract class". You could also try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/512505/185870