# Is there a neat way to mark an entire module full of methods as deprecated?

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby class which contains a lot of logic which will no longer be used but I need to keep around (for a while at least) for backwards-compatibility.

My plan is to move these methods to a module like `LegacyStuff` and include it in the class. I'm wondering if there's a neat way to add something such that when any method in the module is called, a warning is generated, without having to actually add `warn` statements to every individual method body.

I guess what I'm looking for is behaviour like a 'before call' or 'after call' hook on a whole module. I guess the sub-question here is "is this even a good idea?"

Comment: *"is this even a good idea?"* -- The fact that you have one module so big that this question has even occurred to you is the real problem IMO! At least you're changing how it works, now...

Comment: You could probably do it with some `method_added` magic.

Comment: You can (heavily) adapt my answer for another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/50908899/681520 to do this, at least I think it should give you some tips.

Comment: "is this even a good idea?" - it's not a bad idea. The concrete implementation might be bad, but the idea is fine.

Comment: It's a fair point, @TomLord, though it was mostly just me trying to avoid repeating `warn` throughout the module if I didn't have to. In this case, there're only a dozen methods or so in this legacy module. Also, can you believe I've been writing ruby for 10 years and never used `method_added`!? Very useful - thanks!

Comment: @Beejamin "I've been writing ruby for 10 years and never used method_added" - me too. Unless you're into heavy MP, you don't need it at all. :)

Comment: Yeah, you can do some [pretty crazy stuff with `method_added`](https://github.com/tom-lord/search_warrant/blob/6e144eb4c15a1aa2530f04bcb172b0cbdb4bb4ed/lib/search_warrant.rb#L38-L67) :)

Comment: @TomLord yeah as long as you make sure to have an appropriate guard clause `return if @_adding_a_method` when using `define_method` inside `method_added` otherwise you end up with a horrible recursive call :)

Comment: @engineersmnky Using `Module#prepend` makes it much easier to do that sort of thing. I intentionally wrote that code *without* `Module#prepend` as a key part of the challenge :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

First create a module containing a single module method, `setup`. This module could be put in a file that is required as needed. This module method will be invoked from a module containing instance methods to be included in a given class. Using aliases, it modifies those instance methods to print a message (containing the method name) before executing the remainder of its code.

*Module AddMessage*

```
module AddMessage
  def self.setup(mod, msg_pre, msg_post)
    mod.instance_methods(false).
        each do |m|
          am = "_#{m}".to_sym
          mod.send(:alias_method, am, m)
          mod.send(:private, am)
          mod.send(:define_method, m) do |*args, &block|
            puts "%s %s %s" % [msg_pre, m, msg_post] 
            send(am, *args, &block)
          end
        end
  end
end
```

*Module to be included in class*

```
module LegacyStuff
  def old1
    "hi"
  end
  def old2(a, b)
    yield(a, b)
  end
  AddMessage.setup(self, "Warning:", "is deprecated")
end
```

`AddMessage::setup` is passed three arguments, the name of the calling module and a message *prefix* and message *suffix* that are used to form the warning message. When an instance method `m` in this module is executed by a class instance the message `"Warning: #{m} is deprecated"` is printed (e.g., `"Warning: old1 is deprecated"`) before the remaining calculations are performed.

**Use**

`LegacyStuff` is simply included by a class.

```
class C
  include LegacyStuff
  # <constants, methods and so forth go here>
end

c = C.new
c.old1
  # Warning: old1 is deprecated
  #=> "hi"
c.old2(1,2) { |a,b| a+b }
  # Warning: old2 is deprecated
  #=> 3
c.cat
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `cat' for #<C:0x000000008ef0a8>
```

**Explanation of the module method `AddMessage:setup`**

The following (of the generally less-familiar) methods are used by this method: [Module#instance_methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods), [Module#alias_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-alias_method), [Module#private](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-private) and [Module#define_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method).

The following three steps are performed for each instance method `m` defined in module `mod` (e.g., elements of the array `LegacyStuff.instance_methods(false)`).

**`mod.send(:alias_method, am, m)`**

Create an alias `am` of the method (e.g., `_:old1` for `old1`).

**`mod.send(:private, am)`**

Make the alias `am` a private method (e.g., `_old1`).

**`mod.send(:define_method, m) do |*args, &block| ... end`**

Redefine the method `m` (e.g., `old1`) to print the indicate string and then execute the alias `am` (e.g., `_old1`).

Comment: Interesting approach. I would ideally like something that is contained to the `LegacyStuff` module if possible, though.

Comment: I hope this Take #24 is a wrap.

Comment: That is beautiful. Thanks for all the effort - exceptional answer and explanation.

Answer (score 4):

While this is not exactly what you asked ("mark all methods at once") and there probably exists something like this in ruby itself or big frameworks like rails, it might still be useful to somebody.

```
module DeprecatedMethods
  def deprecated(method_name)
    prepend(Module.new do
      define_method method_name do |*args|
        puts "calling deprecated method #{method_name}"
        super(*args)
      end
    end)
  end

end

module AncientCode
  extend DeprecatedMethods

  deprecated def foo # selectively mark methods as deprecated
    puts "doing foo"
  end

  def bar
    puts "doing bar"
  end
end

class Host
  include AncientCode
end

host = Host.new
host.foo
host.bar
# >> calling deprecated method foo
# >> doing foo
# >> doing bar
```

Currently this injects a module per deprecated method, which is kinda wasteful. You can put all deprecated methods in one module, by doing something like this:

```
deprecated_methods :foo, :bar
```

Comment: Also, it is trivial to combine this with `method_added` and get a blanket deprecation thingie.